# Better way to determine date

Tags: javascript

I am looking for best practice on how I may write this function more efficiently.

```
  var d = new Date(),
      time = d.getHours(),
      day  = d.getDay();

  if (day > 0 || day < 7){
    if (time > 18 || time < 8){
      // execute code

    }    
  }
```

Comment: What makes you think your current code is inefficient?

Comment: I thought there may be a way to run everything in one if statement to make it more efficient.  I am not really sure just looking to see if I can optimize.

Comment: Yes, you can combine the two `if` statements into one with the logical AND operator `&&`, but I don't think the efficiency difference will be noticeable, if there is one at all. If you find your current code more readable, there's nothing wrong in keeping it as it is.

Comment: You are doing something I see a lot of new programmers do, which is worrying about *efficiency* (to the point of silliness) when there's *lots and lots* of better stuff a new programmer *should* be worrying about. Some free advice (that's worth its cost, I'm sure): Don't ask any more questions about efficiency until you know enough to ask questions about efficiency, at which time you will no longer want to ask questions about efficiency.

Comment: @lwburk Don't the 2 go hand in hand?  I am just trying to learn through example.

Comment: @user10480 - You're using a PC that can perform billions of instructions every second. How many *billions* of instructions do you think you can save here? Get my point? Any change you make will be imperceptible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( (day > 0 || day < 7) && (t > 18 || t < 8))
```

Is this what you want?

Second condition will only be evaluated only if the first one is true. If the first one is true, then only the second one is evaluated.

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: But, `(day > 0 || day < 7)` makes no sense to me. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I do not want my code to run on Sat / Sun. Is this wrong?

Comment: @jnolte, Saturday is day `6`, since days are zero-based.

Comment: @jnolte Have a look at this. http://sprunge.us/NGKi I guess, this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first conditional to

```
if(day>0)
```

The Date.getDay() function always returns an integer between 0 - 6 so it will never be greater than or equal to seven.